# sp2-0310 error on 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am using Oracle 11g. I'm unable to run my .sql file in sql-plus.

I've searched online help and there are so many people recommending to go to the specific folder and then invoke the sql plus. I'm doing same but having no success.

- Another solution is recommending to go to Oracle home and save file there. This technique runs the file, but whenever i need to modify this file window do not allow me to modify.

My requirement is this, How i run my

> abc.sql

file which is stored in

> D:/sqlscripts

folder. What exactly i should write in my sql plus to run this file.
I'm currently using

> @/D:/sqlscripts/abc.sql

but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL*Plus takes paths as is and just passes them done. This means you have an extra slash at the beginning of the path, and you should stop converting Windows style back-slashes (`\`) to unix style slashes (`/`):

```
@D:\sqlscripts\abc.sql
```